# A finite abelian group whose order is divisible by 10 contains an element of order 10

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

It is given that the order of some finite abelian group is divisible by 10. Prove that the group has a cyclic subgroup of order 10.

It is clear that since order of group is divisible by 10. By converse to Lagrange's Theorem, 
if 10 divides the order of the group G, then G has a subgroup of order 10.

But to ensure that this subgroup is cyclic.

Comment: "If $m$ divides the order of the group $G$, then $G$ has a subgroup of order $10$". Setting aside the fact that the converse of Lagrange's theorem does not hold in general (though it *does* hold for abelian groups, but it has to be *proven* for abelian groups), that sentence does not make much sense: the consequent is independent of $m$.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin: Thanks, for your reply. I have edited the question now. It is mentioned here that order of G is divisible by 10 and G is a finite abelian group, then using Lagrange's Theorem, we can infer that G has a subgroup H of order 10. Then, by Fundamental Theorem of Finite abelian groups, we can conclude that as H is a finite ableian, it is isomorphic to Z2 X Z5 ( external direct product), and is cyclic.

Comment: No: Lagrange's Theorem goes in the **opposite** direction. Lagrange's Theorem says that if $G$ is a finite group, and $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then $|H|$ divides $|G|$. You are trying to invoke Lagrange's Theorem to claim that if $m$ divides $|G|$, then $G$ has a subgroup of order $m$. *That is not Lagrange's Theorem*, and while the result does hold for abelian groups, the proof requires some work and it does *not* follow from Lagrange's Theorem. Have you actually proven this converse for abelian groups?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Thanks , you are right. I was trying to use the converse to the Lagrange's Theorem, which I guess holds for finite cyclic groups. I think a Corollary to Fundamental Theorem of Finite Abelian groups, which says that " If m divides the order of a finite abelian group G, then G has a subgroup of order m" can be used. Please suggest how to move ahead.

Comment: *If* you have that converse already proven, then you can go ahead (it can also be proven inductively by applying Cauchy's Theorem to construct a subgroup one prime at a time, so you don't need the full force of the Fundamental Theorem). Once you know $G$ has a subgroup of order $10$, you need to show an abelian group of order 10 must be cyclic. HINT: if $a$ has order $2$ and $b$ has order $5$ (such elements exist by Cauchy's Theorem), what is the order of $ab$?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: I got your point.If a is of order 2 and b is of order 5, then ab is of order 10 and generates a subgroup of order 10, which is cyclic.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:If $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes then $\mathbb{Z}_p\times\mathbb{Z}_q\cong \mathbb{Z}_{pq}$.

Comment: How on earth does this help? Surely not all abelian groups are isomorphic to $Z_n$? Or perhaps I just haven't covered this yet in my book...

Comment: The fundamental theorem of abelian groups state that all finitely generated abelian groups are a finite product of cyclic groups. In this case there is only one possibility. Not all naturals are product of just two primes, you may think in $4=2\times2$.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Unfortunately I have a few similar question to the asker but do not have the FTAG yet however.

Answer (score 6):

$G$ has a subgroup of order $2$ and order $5$ by Cauchy's theorem. Since $2$ is prime to $5$, the order of the product of two generators of these groups is $10$ and it generates then a (cyclic) subgroup of $G$ of order $10$.

Comment: Lagrange's theorem doesn't guarantee the existence of subgroups of order 2 and 5 (the converse of Lagrange's theorem isn't true in general).  Cauchy's theorem does however give us elements of orders 2 and 5, and thus subgroups of orders 2 and 5.

Comment: k, just didn't remember whose that theorem was from... :p changed the name of the result. Thanks.

Comment: Note that, to conclude that the product of an element of order 2 and an element of order 5 has order 10, it is very important that the group be abelian. Otherwise the order of the product could be anything.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** What abelian groups of order 10 can you think of?

(There is only one, up to isomorphism.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. By Fundamental Theorem of finite abelian group, there is only one Z2+Z5 of order 10, which is cyclic.

Comment: @Tav: Precisely!